# solr jdbc throws and exception as if something is wrong within implementation there

Tags: jdbc, solr, driver

I am trying to check the solr jdbc driver.
It seems to be working only with DbVisualizer & squirrelSQL.
As it is totally undocumented (properties, etc.) I've no idea what is the issue, but I keep on getting some weird error :

> java.sql.SQLException which results from java.io.IOException which
>   results from org.noggit.JSONParser$ParserException: JSON Parse Error
>   char=<

It seems like internally something is going wrong there, as the engine expects JSON and receives XML.

The code is super straight forward :

```
Class.forName("org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.DriverImpl");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:solr://zootest01:2181/?collection=mycol");

Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select item_id from mycol limit 10");
```

The above is the most straightforward code for Java using JDBC.

The executeQuery will always throw an exception.

What is more weird is that tools like DBeaver has the same problem exactly.

I couldn't find any explanation to this behavior, unless something in the implementation is somehow hard-coded to the above 2 specific tools.

Comment: That sounds like the Solr server returning an error message - i.e. returning HTML and not JSON. Check the server log on the Solr side - it should show a stack trace.

Comment: The solr engine side doesn't show anything. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be any setting which sets the results to be XML rather than JSON, as SOLR doesn't work that way. I cannot understand how it is, that some tools are working and others not, as the JDBC protocol is defined quite well.

Comment: Have you tried to use wireshark or ngrep / tcpdump to see what response the driver is actually getting from the server when you create the connection and issue the statement? The JDBC protocol is only relevant between the different Java libraries, isn't it - it doesn't mandate anything between the client and server?